# Google Play Service Froyo -Jar does not contain package com.google.android.gms.ads

Tags: android, admob, google-play-services

I referenced google play services lib as a library resources to ads from google admob, as per their instructions. But I was getting error for class Adview and AdRequest. When I unzipped the google play services jar I could not locate the package com.google.android.gms.ads. What could be the solution to the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google Mobile Ads / Admob was added in [Google Play Services 4.0](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2013/10/google-play-services-40.html), which is not available for Froyo:

> With over 97% of devices now running Android 2.3 (Gingerbread) or newer platform versions, we’re dropping support for Froyo from this release of the Google Play services SDK in order to make it possible to offer more powerful APIs in the future. That means you will not be able to utilize these new APIs on devices running Android 2.2 (Froyo).

You must use the regular Google Play Services library, currently at version 4.4, if you want access to Google Mobile Ads.